# Can't set ChromeType to none for custom web part

Tags: 2013, web-part, variations

I have a site collection with variations on.

Arabic (source)
English (target)

I have added a custom web part on a page. If I edit that web part (I am not doing it programmatically), go to its Properties and then set ChromeType to None in Arabic page then it works fine.

But if I do the same for English site page then ChromeType is not set to None. It doesn't show any error, nothing and no matter how many times I set it to None, it goes back to "Default".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this behaviour specific only to this webpart or is there an issue also with other (custom) webparts?

Comment: To be frank, I have seen lots of problem when working with Arabic and English variations.. So I'm not shocked :)